# In App Purchase not Working in iOS with Monthly Subscription Product

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have did below code for In App Purchase, But when it prompts to enter App Store UserId and Password, It fires - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
 method with SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased two three or any number of times. It is very strange situation with me right now. I have also tried with IAP library but same result. I have In App Purchase working for Non-Consumable Product using same code but not working with Monthly Subscription Product.

In below code @"30" is the product id.

```
-(void)requestProducts{
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"30"]];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
}



-(void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
NSLog(@"%@", response.products);

[self performSelector:@selector(startTransaction:) withObject:[response.products objectAtIndex:0] afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)startTransaction:(SKProduct *)product{
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{
NSLog(@"failedTransaction");
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
{
    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    // Optionally, display an error here.
}else if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentInvalid){
    NSLog(@"Invalid");
}else if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed){
    NSLog(@"Not Allowed");
}else if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorClientInvalid){
    NSLog(@"ClientInvalid");
}else if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorStoreProductNotAvailable){
    NSLog(@"ProductNotAvailable");
}else if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorUnknown){
    NSLog(@"Unknown");
}
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{
NSLog(@"restoreTransaction");
//[self recordTransaction: transaction];
//[self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{
NSLog(@"completeTransaction");
// Your application should implement these two methods.
//[self recordTransaction: transaction];
//[self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
// Remove the transaction from the payment queue.
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you are doing a "Monthly Subscription Product".  If that is an autorenewable IAP then each purchase from a new test user will generate 5-6 renewal transactions, one every 5 minutes.  If you wait 30 minutes you would expect 5 or 6 calls to updatedTransactions

Comment: Is there any way to handle updatedTransactions method calls when it prompts to enter itunes username/password?